# Converting time_struct with timezone to datetime GMT in Python

Tags: python, date, datetime

I'm retrieving struct_time dates from Feedparser.

Like you can see below, FeedParser automatically parses the dates into GMT (second line, EDT, get converted from 19:19 to 23:19)

FeedParser converted  `Sun, 06 Sep 2020 23:07:16 GMT` into `struct_time((2020, 9, 6, 23, 7, 16, 6, 250, 0))`

FeedParser converted  `Fri, 11 Sep 2020 19:19:01 EDT` into `struct_time((2020, 9, 11, 23, 19, 1, 4, 255, 0))`

When I try to convert the struct_time to a datetime with the below, I get GMT + 1 (my timezone).

```
from datetime import datetime
from time import mktime
datetime.fromtimestamp(mktime(struct_time((2020, 9, 6, 23, 7, 16, 6, 250, 0))))
> datetime.datetime(2020, 9, 7, 0, 7, 16)
```

How can I convert these struct_time into datetimes GMT?

Comment: the [struct_time](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.struct_time) timetuple already refers to UTC, so what exactly is your expected output? a time zone aware datetime object?

Comment: End goal is to store the date as DATETIME objects in an SQL database in UTC, so the output is a datetime object in UTC

Comment: besides the option I show in my answer, `fromtimestamp` also has a [tz attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp) which you could set to timezone.utc. the thing here is that Python by default assumes that you want *local* time unless you explicitly specifiy the time zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

to get a time zone aware datetime object, you could unpack the relevant part of the timetuple into a datetime object and set the tzinfo attribute to UTC:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone

# given a time_struct tuple like
s = (2020, 9, 6, 23, 7, 16, 6, 250, 0)
# convert to datetime object as
dt = datetime(*s[:6], tzinfo=timezone.utc)
print(dt)
>>> 2020-09-06 23:07:16+00:00
```